# Memory leak with com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory-leaks, jboss

I'm running application on JBoss 6.3 server, deployed on Oracle RedHat Linux 6.5.

JBoss configuration:  -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

[image]
[image]